# How to change content that displays on a page using *ngIf and url path

Tags: angular

I have a page on my angular4 and i want to change the div content that displays using *ngIf, based of the url that comes through.

So if url is homepage it should hide a particular div and let another one show

if url is about it should show a particular div and hide another

Thanks guys.. any idea would be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use routing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you should get the Url parameters from the http params and assign them into a variable in your ts file.
now in the current html page ( component )  , do an *ngIf to check whether that variable is  == 'about'  or whatever you want.
and to make it happen on the html page , you could do something like this
div *ngIf="{{variable}}=='about'" ; else fromhomepage; 
content to show when variable=about ..
below

content from home page..

Answer (score 0):

Url based content changes is best done via Routing...

Only for parameterized routes, you should be using custom logic to show/hide content using ngIf (upon parameter retrieved from the ActivatedRoute object)